# Rewrite URL based off of IP on OpenWRT

Tags: linux, proxy, linux-networking, transparent-proxy, openwrt

We are running OpenWRT on a WRT54GL. I have been looking for an answer to this, but I can't seem to figure out what to search for, if its possible, or what combination of programs to use.

I want to be able to redirect a HTTP request from a WiFi device based off of their MAC address. This should all be transparent to the device.

Basically we are trying to redirect any non-registered devices to a website to register the device (at this point, we would push a new config to the router that would allow this MAC address "full access"). Once a device is registered, it will be redirected to a transparent squid proxy server on another machine for caching/blocking certain sites.

I looked at tinyproxy -> popilo which redirects but I won't have the MAC address to know if its registered or not.

Any help (google suggestions, programs, anything!) would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of solutions that can do this. The following are a few examples.

- [Sputnik](http://www.sputnik.com/)
- [Hotspot System](http://www.hotspotsystem.com/)
- [Chillispot](http://www.chillispot.info/)
- [NoCat](http://nocat.net/)

I pulled all of those from a [dd-wrt](http://dd-wrt.com/) (similar to OpenWRT) router (it has others, but those are the big ones). I'm not sure how complex they would be to get working on OpenWRT, but given that they're all installed by default in dd-wrt, it must be possible.